# Sprint factory iphone 5 unlocking

Tags: iphone, unlock

I want to factory unlock my iphone 5 from Sprint operator. Can it be done for free or have I use an internet ? Thanks for helping:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [this](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1608123/unlocking-read.html). Unfortunately, it is completely illegal, and almost impossible, unless you are off the contract. If you are currently off the contract, see [this](http://www.sprint.com/legal/unlocking_policy.html).